# Remove button based on current state

Tags: javascript, html, button, hide

I'm trying to remove the display of a button if the content is showing / not showing, see code below.

```
<div id="bottomdrawer" class="mui--no-user-select">
        <button id="hide">hide</button>
        <button id="show">show</button>
        <div class="bottom-menu" id="bottommenu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Inbox (1)</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Add a Spot</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Community Forum</a></li>
            </ul>

            <button type="button" name="button">Upgrade to Premium</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
        $("#bottommenu").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
        $("#bottommenu").show();
    });
```

if content is showing, remove the show button, if the content is hidden show the hide button.

Comment: Still vague. Explain more...

Comment: updated @ibrahimmahrir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using only one button, and a boolean to keep track of the state (showing/hidding):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var state = true;                         // record which state are we on (are we showing or hiding).
    $("#toggle").click(function() {           // on click of the toggle button
        state = !state;                       // invert the state
        $("#bottommenu").toggle(state);       // change the visibility of the menu accordingly
        $(this).text(state? "HIDE": "SHOW");  // change the text of the button accordingly
    });
});
```

```css
#bottommenu {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="toggle">HIDE</button>
<div id="bottommenu"></div>
```

Comment: you my friend are a legend

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you want the `#bottommenu` content to be shown initially, this does what you want:

```js
// Initially hide the show button
$("#show").hide();

$("#hide").click(function(){
  $("#bottommenu, #hide").hide();
  $("#show").show();
});

$("#show").click(function(){
  $("#bottommenu, #hide").show();
  $("#show").hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="bottomdrawer" class="mui--no-user-select">
  <button id="hide">hide</button>
  <button id="show">show</button>
  <div class="bottom-menu" id="bottommenu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Inbox (1)</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friends</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Add a Spot</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Community Forum</a></li>
    </ul>
    <button type="button" name="button">Upgrade to Premium</button>
  </div>
</div>
```